# Scale font only vertically (poor man’s condensed of Libertine)

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, scaling, libertine

I’m using Linux Libertine to typeset the translation of a poem with `eledmac`/`eledpar`. The original text appears on the left pages and the translation on the right ones. Since the translated verses are longer then the original once it happens often that a single word of the translated verse breaks in a new line. This is ok, but I thought about scaling the font of the translated font slightly in the vertical direction to create a *poor man’s condensed* version of Libertine.

I know that this is not the best way but I want at least see if it looks that bad.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe,textwidth=70mm}

\begin{document}
This is a text that is a little to long for this line.

\addfontfeatures{Scale=0.965}
This is a text that is a little to long for this line.
\end{document}
```

[image: scaled fonts]

I’m aware of `fontspec`’s `Width` option, but it won’t work for Libertine and `Scale` affects width and height.

All solutions taking an argument (e.g. `\scalebox`) wont work here, because I can’t wrap all verses in such a macro. So I need a switch like `\addfontfeature` or something else.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user22108: How to scale a font vertically only ;-) (ps. Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Font feature `FakeStrech` might help:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
This is a text that is a little to long for this line.

{\addfontfeatures{Scale=0.5}
This is a text that is a little to long for this line.}

{\addfontfeatures{FakeStretch=.5}
This is a text that is a little to long for this line.}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is what I was looking for :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{letterspace}

\textls[-17]{This is a text that is a little to long for this line.}
```

Works for pdflatex.

Comment: I’m using XeTeX, so this won’t help. Furthermore your solution will reduce the space between the letters but not the letter size itself …