# poor man's condensed with pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am looking for a solution to create "poor man's condensed" with pdflatex. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136943/scale-font-only-vertically-poor-mans-condensed-of-libertine) I found an answer that works with XeTeX, however it uses package `fontspec`, but I need something for pdflatex. And as in the referenced question, wrapping the condensed stuff with, say, `\scalebox{0.9}[1]`  is not an option as I need  the condensed text to allow linebreaking ...

In case it helps: I am using the `mycrotype`package anyway and from reading its documentation I understand that it uses ad hoc condensing and widening per line behind the scenes, so I guess *something* should be possible somehow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\textcondensed#1{\scalebox[0.9]{1}{#1}} % This is almost fine, except line breaking

\begin{document}
This is just some normal text, but the latin phrase
\textcondensed{lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
that it contains is typeset in condesed.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's "condensed"?

Comment: @Jubobs Letters should keep their heights but become slightly smaller horizontally (e.g. if big O is a circle it should become more elliptical). A *proper* (not poor man's) condensed font would make considerations for stroke witdths etc., but for not so strong condensing something "mechanical" should suffice.

Comment: seems like an accident  news headline

Comment: If you're installing fonts yourself, `otftotfm` offers an option `--extend` which you can set to a value below 1.

Comment: @percusse I see your point, poor man indeed :)

Comment: @StephanLehmke Would you care to elaborate? I must admit I'm always getting lost between all those files making up a font (.pfb, .vf, .afm, .tfm, .map, .fd) and their interdependencies ...

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm/52902#52902) on installing fonts, which works for `ttf` and `otf` fonts. As the tool `otftotfm` used for this does almost all of the work and allows to "make" a condensed font by just adding an option, this wouldn't be a lot of work.

Comment: Why not just use a font which has a condensed variant and is already configured for use with pdflatex? I think I'm missing something here... (Maybe you must use a particular font? Or...?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **poor** solution via microtype (the last line of a paragraph is problematic):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[selected=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetExpansion
   [ context = poorcondensed,
     stretch = -100,
     shrink = 100,
     step    = 1 ]
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,TS1} }
   { }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

{\microtypecontext{expansion=poorcondensed}%
 \lipsum[1-2]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's *too* poor.

Comment: @egreg I agree... Especially as this (very poor) solution only works with a whole paragraph.

Comment: Ouch... But since you might as well be hanged for a sheep as a lamb, you could also add some negative letterspacing.